# How to remove the previous data shown in Telerik RadTextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-radinput

If I enter text in a Telerik `RadTextBox` it shows the previously inputted data. How can prevent/remove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `AutoComplete` property. Set it as `Disabled`.